# How to pass a List of JRBeanCollectionDataSource to a subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am generating a report from a JRBeanCollectionDataSource. This report is about a customer's order.

This is my code

```
public class Customer
{
    private String customerName;
    private String customerNo;
    private String customerAddress;
    private ArrayList<CustomerOrder> customerOrders;
    //Getters and Setters
}


private class CustomerOrder
{
    private String itemName;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private int itemQuantity;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

When a customer a report containing the customer details and a list of the customer orders need to be generated.
Since `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` takes a collection, this is what i did.

```
Customer cust; //Customer Instance

ArrayList<Customer> custList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
custList.add(cust); 

JRBeanCollectionDataSource rptData = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(custList);
```

How can i extract the `CustomerOrder` list in `Customer` and pass it as a subreport?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to set the datasource expression for the subreport:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{customerOrders})
```

The resulting xml should have a subreport tag that resembles:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement uuid="e9fc4a60-3844-41b7-a38c-768f06f09b44" x="0" y="57" width="555" height="68"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{customerOrders})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report2_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

The only other thing you need to check is that the `Language` for the report properties is set to `Java`.